# Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Error! Missing Or invalid Module name

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I tried to verify my contract with constructor arguments but hardhat throwing that error everytime

```
npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby 0x50a45120252c2FeeD06915F46D8Fbabec1a008df "TestSmartContract" "TSC" "my_ipfs_link1" "my_ipfs_link2"
```

these arguments is same as my contract's arguments
[image]

Comment: verifying solidity code with anything other than remix has been a pain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade the plugin version to 3.0.1 like this solves the issue:

```
npm i -s @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@3.0.1
```

Comment: this fixed the issue OP describes but then in the end it failed anyway with Reason: Fail - Unable to verify. Any idea?

Comment: ah then this is because the arguments u inputed for verification is not correct, it's not a hardhat issue:)

Comment: But my constructor doesn't take any arguments ..

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to occur with the 3.0.2 version of @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan, it is fixed in the latest version 3.0.3. Please upgrade to the latest version (3.0.3) to fix it or use 3.0.1.